# Criterion for expectation of $g(X)$

Tags: probability, integration

The problem is

> > Let $X$ be a nonnegative random variable, $g$ be a nonnegative, strictly increasing and differentiable function, then
> >     $$E\,g(X)<\infty \Longleftrightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} g'(n)P(X>n)<\infty$$

what I know is 
$$E\,g(X)=g(0)+\int_0^{\infty} g'(x)P(X>x)\,dx$$
but how to continue? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I believe this requires some additional hypothesis on $g$.

Comment: This doesn't seem right: take something like $P(X=n)=\frac{6}{\pi^2} \frac{1}{n^2}$ so that $P(X>n) \sim 1/n$, now build $g$ such that $g'(n)=n$ but $g'$ rapidly decays in a vicinity of $n$, such that $g$ is actually bounded. Then $E[g(X)]<\infty$ but the sum on the right diverges. To get this conclusion, you need to somehow argue that $g'(n)$ is a decent approximation for $g'$ on the whole interval $[n-1/2,n+1/2]$.

Comment: @Ian Thanks, I believe this is an error in Theorem 12.3, page 76, of Probability: A Graduate Course by Allan Gut.